Proving that $ \{([w_0 : w_1], [z_0 : z_1 : z_2]) \in \Bbb {CP}^1 \times \Bbb {CP}^2| w_0z_1 = w_1z_0\}$ is a smooth complex hypersurface
Let F be the subset of $\Bbb {CP}^1 \times \Bbb {CP}^2$
defined by
$F = \{([w_0 : w_1], [z_0 : z_1 : z_2]) \in \Bbb {CP}^1 \times \Bbb {CP}^2| w_0z_1 = w_1z_0\}$
I want to prove that F is a smooth complex hypersurface.
define the map $f:\Bbb {CP}^1 \times \Bbb {CP}^2\to \Bbb C:(([w_0 : w_1], [z_0 : z_1 : z_2]))=w_0z_1 - w_1z_0$
My first problem is that this map does not seem to be well-defined. Taking other representatives of each class  $[\lambda w_0 : \lambda w_1], [\lambda' z_0 : \lambda' z_1 : \lambda' z_2]$ yields  $\lambda\lambda'(w_0z_1 - w_1z_0)$, which is in general different from $w_0z_1 - w_1z_0$.
How can I make this map well-defined?
I want to apply the submersion theorem, but I don't know if it makes sense to take partial derivatives w.r.t projective coordinates: for a point $p=([w_0 : w_1], [z_0 : z_1 : z_2]) \in \Bbb {CP}^1 \times \Bbb {CP}^2$. Assuming it does:
$df_p =(\frac{\partial f}{\partial w_0},\frac{\partial f}{\partial w_1},\frac{\partial f}{\partial z_0},\frac{\partial f}{\partial z_1},\frac{\partial f}{\partial z_2})|_p=(z_1 ,-z_0, -w_1, w_0 ,0)$ has rank=1 for $z_0,z_1,w_0,w_1$ not all 0 so we have a submersion because this is the dimension of the codomain of f. Then the submersion theorem yields that F is a sumbmanifold of complex dimension equal to 1, so a hypersurface. Is this correct? If not how do I fix it?
Does smoothness follow also from the submersion theorem?

Your map is indeed not well-defined; however the set of points where it is $0$ is well-defined.

@hunter How can I use then this map if it not well-defined, provided that is that set that I need? Can I defined in another way?

Do you know how to work locally? Locally it is a surface in C^3 and you can use the Jacobian criterion.

@CraniumClamp I am not sure how to do that. Coud you elaborate?

@CraniumClamp Shouldn't it be in C^5 ? since CP^1 is defined on C^2 and CP^2 on C^3?

No, you seem to have a lot of misunderstandings. CP^n is locally C^n. It is n-dimensional after all.
